Covariant index of partial derivative
As an example: when doing a coordinate transformation $x^{\mu} \to \tilde{x}^{\mu}$, the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu} \to \tilde{g}_{\mu \nu}$ transforms as follows:
$$\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\mu}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}} g_{\alpha \beta}$$
Or generally, the forward transform $F^{\mu}_{\nu}$ may be defined:
$$F^{\mu}_{\nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial \tilde{x}^{\nu}}$$
Why does the forward transform $F^{\mu}_{\nu}$ have lower index when the derivative has upper indices?

Could you explain a bit on what the forward transform is?

@LidingYao It is the jacobian of the coordinate transformation. I was watching eigenchris's videos on tensor calculus and he uses it there. Instead of asking about the transform $F^{\mu}{\nu}$, I could have asked about the metric tensor transform $\tilde{g}{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial \tilde{x^{\mu}}} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial \tilde{x^{\nu}}} g_{\alpha \beta}$. Why does $\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu}$ have lower indices when the partial derivative has both indices upper.

They're lower, because the indices are in the denominator. $x^\mu$ has an upper index but $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ has a lower index. The latter is also commonly written as $\partial_\mu$.

@Deane Ok, so it's just a definition?

No. It is consistent with how it changes under a change of coordinates. That’s the real underlying reason for these formulas.

Could you please elaborate?

Consider the situation where coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$ induce coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^n,p_1,\ldots, p_n)$ on $T^*M$. The index $i$ in $$\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$$counts as an upper index. This index balance is dictated by Einstein's summation convention.
